# How to create search BUTTON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create search button to view items from database.

```
<form  method="post" name="searchdeals">
                <h5 class="display-5 text-left py-3">Find a favourite vehicle </h5>
                <div class="form-group select">
                    <select name="manufacturer_code" id="manufacturer_code" class="form-control" onchange="getState(this.value);">
                        <option selected>Select Brand</option>
                        <?php $ret="SELECT * FROM tbl_manufacturer";
                        $query= $dbh -> prepare($ret);
                        $query-> execute();
                        $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
                        {
                            foreach($results as $result)
                            {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->manufacturer_code);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->manufacturer_name);?></option>
                            <?php }} ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group select">
                    <select name="model_code" id="model_code" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Select Model</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="searchdeals" value="Filter" class="btn btn-block btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search Vehicle</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is my form to search items. So can suggest to me how to create query and code to create search button.

I know to use LIKE OPERATOR in query, but i don't know to write the code

action.page

```
if(isset($_POST['searchdeals'])){

$valueToSearch = $_POST['model_code'];

$sql = "SELECT tbl_manufacturer.manufacturer_name, tbl_model.model_name, tbl_model.model_type, tbl_vehicle.*, tbl_company.comp_name
                                    FROM tbl_vehicle
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_company ON tbl_vehicle.comp_id = tbl_company.comp_id
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_vehicle.model_code = tbl_model.model_code
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_manufacturer ON tbl_model.manufacturer_code = tbl_manufacturer.manufacturer_code";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need an action for your form like this:

```
<form  method="post" name="searchdeals" action="/action_page.php">
```

The action_page.php should then contain the code that uses your $_POST variables from your form to build your SELECT statement.

Comment: In action what code must i write? You see code i put, correct?

Comment: action is a URL path to where your target script is.  So it could be an absolute URL like "mywebsite.com/action_page.php" or a relative one if your server allows it like "./../forms/action_page.php" or whatever.  In many cases, it will even be a self referencing URL "_self" where the PHP of the page is designed to look for $_POST variables and apply them if they find them.  It really depends on how you are designing your site.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp is a simple description of how the structure of forms work, as for the backend.  I tend to use mysqli instead of PDO, so someone else might be more qualified to answer that part of the question.

Comment: Oh, and sorry I misspoke, a self referencing URL should be left blank.  "_self" is for targets, not actions.

Comment: Oh, Thanks for help me

Answer (score 1):

In action.php (assuming that this is the file that processes the submitted form), you should use the `WHERE` clause and the search term from the `$_POST` variable. In this case, you are posting `model_code`.

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_manufacturer.manufacturer_name, tbl_model.model_name, tbl_model.model_type, tbl_vehicle.*, tbl_company.comp_name
                                    FROM tbl_vehicle
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_company ON tbl_vehicle.comp_id = tbl_company.comp_id
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_vehicle.model_code = tbl_model.model_code
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_manufacturer ON tbl_model.manufacturer_code = tbl_manufacturer.manufacturer_code 
WHERE tbl_model.model_name like '%" . $_POST['model_code'] . "'%";
```

Not sure if that is the field you have to compare to but you get the idea.

Comment: You should also worry about SQL injections before you push something like this to production.

Comment: Oh, Ok. Thanks for suggestion